# are associations dependent on a database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, associations, heroku

I tested an association on mysql as follows and it works:

```
User.campaigns
```

These are the associations in the Models:

```
Campaign belongs_to :user

User has_many :campaigns
```

However, when I run it on heroku which uses Postgres, I get the following:

```
CampaignsController#index (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) "PGError: ERROR: column campaigns.user_id does not exist\nLINE 1: SELECT * FROM \"campaigns\" WHERE (\"campaigns\".user_id = 1) \n ^\n: SELECT * FROM \"cam
```

This is a little worrying because -- if the way I use rails associations depends on the database...hmm...not sure how I can effectively doing any development...thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you use the same database in dev? What database are you using in dev?

Comment: How did you create the database on Heroku?

Comment: I am using mysql in dev...I haven't found a straighforward way to use postgres locally...any pointers to a good tutorail?  I did a Google and it was pretty cumbersome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error indicates the column doesn't exist. Have you run the migrations on Heroku?

```
$ heroku rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Hi, yeah, I did run them....seemed okay, then ran it again and got an error not related to this model....

Comment: hmm...thinking maybe the migration didn't run completely then...will check, it looked like it did locally though